# How to map in react js

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

In my code I am using map to call my Expense-Item component and if I console I am getting all the values but this is not rendering means it shows nothing on output screen:

```
import React from 'react';
import ExpenseItem from './ExpenseItem';
import Card from '../UI/Card';
import './Expenses.css';
import { useState } from 'react';
import ExpensesFilter from './ExpenseFilter';


const Expenses = (props) => {
  const [filterYear, setFilterYear] = useState("2020");

  const FilterChangeHandler = (filter)=>{
      setFilterYear(filter);
  }

  return (
    <Card className="expenses">
      <ExpensesFilter selected={ filterYear } onFilterChangeHandler = { FilterChangeHandler }/>
      {props.items.map( (expense) =>{
            <ExpenseItem
                title={expense.title}
                amount={expense.amount}
                date={expense.date}
            />
          } 
        )}
    </Card>
  );
}

export default Expenses;
```

Comment: Your callback in map is wrong, you have to put return. i.e. => {return <ExpenseItem... }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Including return you should also check if `props.items` not null and has length to map to avoid breaking UI in these cases. You should modify your code as this,

```
return (
  <Card className="expenses">
    <ExpensesFilter
      selected={filterYear}
      onFilterChangeHandler={FilterChangeHandler}
    />
    {props.items && props.items.length > 0
      ? props.items.map((expense) => {
          return (
            <ExpenseItem
              title={expense.title}
              amount={expense.amount}
              date={expense.date}
            />
          );
        })
      : null}
  </Card>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a `return` statement before your `<ExpenseItem/>` in order to return it from the `.map()`callback and render it. That‘s it.